# Arranging terms in an equation isolating the y term in C

Tags: c

I want to take an ODE equation and isolate the `y''` term.

e.g. `-3xy' -y'' - bcos(t) = asin(t)` becomes `y'' = -3xy' - bcos(t) - asin(t)`.

For example: `4y - 3y' = -y''` would be `y'' = -4y + 3y'`

Rules: The highest order must be `y''` and there will not be a constant in front of the `y''` term so no division is required.

Basically, what I want to do is add '+' signs where needed and then cycle
through the string and whenever I find a '+' on the wrong side of the equals sign
Put a '-' on the other side of it and move whatever characters are between it and the next + or - right after that.

```
example: "-2+y'=3x" 
turns into "-2+y'=+3x"
and then I take that and make it to
"2+y'=+3x+" 
and finally "+y'=+3x+2"
```

Here's my attempt so far although nothing happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fin;
    fin = fopen("diffeq.txt", "r");
    char line[300];
    char from[300];
    char to[300];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++)
        {
            if (from[i] == '=' && from[i + 2] != '-')
                to[i] = '=';
            i++;
            to[i] = '+';
            i++;
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you are reading anything into the `from[]` array.

Comment: my bad I typed this up real quick, but now I copied and pasted this from my actual file. this is the updated version.

Comment: I still don't see where you assign any values to `from[i]`. Do you mean: `if (line[i] == '=' &&....`?

Comment: oh it was another array to store for the '+' sign, i changed the from to line like you said, and now I'm getting something for my output, but it isn't quite pretty. but were off to a start

Comment: You can probably get this to work walking through the string like you are, but I would seriously consider using the `strtok()` function from `string.h` to tokenize the line as @drum is describing below.

Comment: You should avoid code like `if (from[i]... && from[i+2]...)`. That code assumes that the user has formatted the equation exactly the way you expect. However, looking at your own examples, you can see cases where you have a space on both sides of a minus sign, and other cases where you don't. A good parser should never make assumptions about the number of space characters in the input.

Comment: i just got finished with learning how to tokenize text and i split them and printed them, but now i don't know how to store "y'" || "y''" into an array called LHS. is it a reach if i ask how can i do this?

Comment: It's an awful job to do this from C. You need to build an expression parser and symbolic algebra rules from the ground up. it is possible of course.

Comment: Using `strtok()` is unlikely to be a good idea; it zaps the delimiter character it finds with a null byte, destroying the information you need.  You should look up `strcspn()` (and `strspn()` and `strpbrk()`) for this sort of input string.  Your sample data seems to have blanks at key points, in which case you might be able to get away with `strtok()`, but equations are often written without the spaces.  I'm left wondering whether `asin(t)` is the arc-sine of `t` or `a×sin(t)`, and whether `bcos(t)` is `b×cos(t)` or something else.

Comment: Agreed with @JonathanLeffler. It's better to loop through the string and manually tokenizing depending on the operation.

Comment: i agree the spacing is horrible and limits me, that's why i went with the tokenizer. its a*sin(t) not arcsin(t) but i don't think that really matters as I'm not solving anything, just arranging text. http://hastebin.com/kasalifozi.cpp here is another code but when i run it it crashes, so I have no idea anymore

Answer (score 1):

The way you can do it is tokenizing by its terms in both left-hand-size and right-hand-side.

1. Have 2 string arrays: let's call them `lhs` and `rhs`
2. Loop through the equation and tokenize the terms and store them into their respective arrays.

Eg:

```
lhs = ["-3x","+2","-y"]
rhs = ["+4y","-5"]
```

3. Now create 2 new string arrays to store the reorganized lhs and rhs. Let's call them `new_lhs` and `new_rhs`.
4. Iterate through both `lhs` and `rhs` and place all `non-y` terms in `new_lhs` and all `y` terms in `new_rhs`.
5. Simplify the terms.
6. Join both `new_lhs` and `new_rhs` into a new string.

EDIT: You can make this variable `agnostic` by wrapping this in a function and pass in the variable you want to solve for.

For example:

```
char* solve_for_variable(char* variable, char* equation);
```

Comment: hey drum, thanks for the input. since I'm reading from a text file, i will start out with one string and then tokenize it to split into two arrays, lhs and rhs. the only thing that I'm kind of stuck on is storing the new tokenized terms into the arrays. i just got finished with learning how to tokenize text and i split them and printed them, but now i don't know how to store "y'" || "y''" into LHS. is it a reach if i ask how can i do this?

Comment: @nicolepanda You can do a substring `strstr` to see if a term has a variable http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/