# How do I store tokenized strings into arrays in C

Tags: c

In my program I read some text that contains the string "`y'`" and "`y''`" and I want to store that into my array called lhs[100] and the rest of the text goes into rhs[100].

How do I do this? I am stuck on deciding if it works with `strstr()` or `strcpy()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fin;
    fin = fopen("diffeq.txt", "r");
    char line[100];
    char split[] = " +-";
    char* token;
    char lhs[100];
    char rhs[100];
    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin) != NULL)
    {
        for (token = strtok(line, split); token; token = strtok(NULL, split))
        {
            // I need to find from the token the string "y'" and "y''"
            // and store them into array "lhs[100]" and the rest of the
            // contents stored into "rhs[100]"
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `strtok()` is an appalling choice of tokenizer; it zaps the delimiter, so you can't tell whether it was space or plus or minus that appeared where there is a null byte after `strtok()` has tokenized.  (Well, if you work on a copy of the string you can work out what the character was, but the key point is that `strtok()` is destructive.)

Comment: 'Tis intriguing that there's also the question [Arranging terms in an equation isolating the `y` term in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927869/arranging-terms-in-an-equation-isolating-the-y-term-in-c) which is asking about similar issues — but it appears to be a different person asking.

Comment: `strstr()` is a search function; it can't copy.  `strcpy()` is a copy function; it or something related (`memmove()` or `memcpy()`, for example) might be used to copy a string from the token found by `strtok()` into `lhs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working on a sample text. i tested and it works fine. so just you should add `read file to text` statements. also if you want to add a space between tokens, remove comment sign from `//token[j++] = ' ';`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char text[] = "this is a y' sample y'' text y ynot?";
    int len = strlen(text);
    char token[50];
    char lhs[100];
    char rhs[100];
    int state = 0;
    int i, j = 0;
    token[0] = '\0';
    lhs[0] = '\0';
    rhs[0] = '\0';
    printf("\nlen: %d", len);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        switch (text[i]) {
        case ' ':
        case '+':
        case '-':
            //token[j++] = ' ';
            token[j] = '\0';
            //printf("\ntoken> %s", token);
            // separator is seen, check the token 
            if (state == 2 || state == 3)
                // token is "y'" or "y''"
                strcat(lhs, token);
            else
                // other token detected
                strcat(rhs, token);
            state = 0;
            j = 0;
            break;
        case 'y':
            token[j++] = text[i];
            if (state == 0)
                // first 'y' is detected
                state = 1;
            else
                state = 0;
            break;
        case '\'':
            token[j++] = text[i];
            if (state == 1)
                // we had token=="y" so now we have token=="y'"
                state = 2;
            else if (state == 2)
                // we had token=="y'" so now we have token=="y''"
                state = 3;
            else state = 0;
            break;
        default:
            token[j++] = text[i];
            state = 0;
            break;
        }
    // check token detection condition for last token
    if (state == 2 || state == 3)
        strcat(lhs, token);
    else
        strcat(rhs, token);

        printf("\n\nlhs> %s\nrhs> %s", lhs, rhs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear what you want, but strtok() is fine for your purpose and you are uisng it correctly. The only issue is what to do with the tokens once you have them.

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin) != NULL)
{
   /* for each line */
   strcpy(lhs, "");  /* ser lhs and rhs to the empty string */
   strcpy(rhs, "");

   for(token = strtok(line, split), token, token =strtok(NULL, split))
   {
      /* for each token */
      /* match the tokens, Actually a redundant test in there but make it obvious*/
      if(strstr(token, "y'") || strstr(token, "y''"))
        strcat(lhs, token);
      else
        strcat(rhs, token);
   }
}
```

Seems to be what you hope to achieve. Tokens matching in lhs, tokens not matching in rhs.

Comment: Yes, a typo, Fixed.

Comment: what a blessing this is, thanks, but youre right about the issue of knowing what to do next with them hah